# Flutter: IPA build finds the GoogleService-Info.plist in folder A but it does not find it in folder B?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase

I have a pipeline that should build me 2 IPA files with different schemes and firebase connection but meanwhile the first type file built successfully:

[image]

The second throws this:

```
Xcode build done.                                           67.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.ZgjruG/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirXYq2SP/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    Configuration is: uat-type
    cp: /Users/runner/work/1/s/flavors/ios/Runner/Firebase/uat/GoogleService-Info.plist: No such file or directory
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.ZgjruG/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirXYq2SP/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Encountered error while building for device.
##[error]Error: The process '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/3.3.2/macos/flutter/bin/flutter' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Flutter Build App - iOS
```

As you can see the files in XCode can be seen:

[image]

It finds the file at `Firebase/cicd` but not at `Firebase/uat`.

This is the script I use to copy the file based on configuration:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-cicd" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-cicd" ]; then cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/cicd/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"
fi

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-uat" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-uat" ]; then cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/uat/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"
fi
```

I wonder if anyone has any idea what could be the problem, what should I try to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you included uat file, XCode has sometimes problem if you dont include file into project through XCode

Comment: Same way I did with the cicd file...